# Objective-C switch defines contents of string

Tags: objective-c, string, switch-statement

I've come from a java background, so i'm still getting to grips with some of the ways of doing things with Obj-C.

Depending on a number provided, I want an NSString variable to have different contents.

In java I would do something like this:

```
string foo;
switch (numberToSwtich){

    case 1:
       foo = "Something!";
       break;
    case 2:
       foo = "Something Else!";
       break;
}
```

Obviously there are two types of String in objective-c. NSString and NSSMutableString.

The difference being that you can change one at a later date. However, like java, can I initialize a NSString first then set its contents later or do I need to use an NSMutableString?

Something a bit like this...

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] init];

switch ([self getNumberOfSides]) {
    case 1:
        aString = @"A String"; 
        break;
    case 2:
        aString = @"Another String"; 
        break;
}
```

I'm aware there are other-ways of doing this, such as using an NSDictionary with numeric keys for example, but I would like to use a switch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid. There's no need to use NSMutableString.

Your code does leak memory, because you're not releasing the empty string you allocated using **alloc**. It's better to use the "string" class method for empty strings:

```
NSString *aString;

switch ([self getNumberOfSides]) {
        case 1:
                aString = @"A String"; 
                break;
        case 2:
                aString = @"Another String"; 
                break;
        default:
                aString = [NSString string];
                break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think that that would work. It's pretty logical. Must be this land of square brackets that is causing me to strange in the head!

Comment: There is no real need or purpose in using [NSString string] - just use @"".  The "string" factory method is there for consistency, and there for use in the mutable version where it is useful ([NSMutableString string]).

Comment: As a general good practice, I'd recommend also saying NSString *aString = nil; It's always good to do that.